# CUPS filter failed error

Tags: cups

I installed CUPS and added my printer but if I print anything I see always "filter failed" error. Could you please check what is wrong?

```
E [04/Jan/2019:19:50:40 +0000] [Job 13] Unable to open raster stream - : Broken pipe
E [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Job stopped due to filter errors; please consult the error_log file for details.
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] The following messages were recorded from 19:50:40 to 19:50:44
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Applying default options...
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Adding start banner page "none".
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Queued on "POS-80-Series" by "root".
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Auto-typing file...
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Request file type is text/plain.
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] File of type text/plain queued by "root".
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Adding end banner page "none".
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] time-at-processing=1546631440
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] 4 filters for job:
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] texttopdf (text/plain to application/pdf, cost 32)
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] pdftopdf (application/pdf to application/vnd.cups-pdf, cost 66)
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] gstoraster (application/vnd.cups-pdf to application/vnd.cups-raster, cost 99)
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] rastertopos (application/vnd.cups-raster to printer/POS-80-Series, cost 0)
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] job-sheets=none,none
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] argv[0]="POS-80-Series"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] argv[1]="13"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] argv[2]="root"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] argv[3]="send.txt"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] argv[4]="1"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] argv[5]="finishings=3 number-up=1 job-uuid=urn:uuid:9c0423ec-3d23-30ab-65e0-845325a1931c job-originating-host-name=localhost date-time-at-creation= date-time-at-processing= time-at-creation=1546631440 time-at-processing=1546631440 document-name-supplied=send.txt"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] argv[6]="/var/spool/cups/d00013-001"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[0]="CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[1]="CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[2]="CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc-root"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[3]="CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[4]="CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[5]="CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[6]="CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[7]="CUPS_STATEDIR=/run/cups"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[8]="HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[9]="PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[10]="SERVER_ADMIN=root@pizzalinkess"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[11]="SOFTWARE=CUPS/2.2.8"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[12]="TMPDIR=/var/spool/cups/tmp"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[13]="USER=root"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[14]="CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[15]="CUPS_SERVER=/run/cups/cups.sock"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[16]="CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[17]="IPP_PORT=631"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[18]="CHARSET=utf-8"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[19]="LANG=en.UTF-8"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[20]="PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/POS-80-Series.ppd"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[21]="RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[22]="CONTENT_TYPE=text/plain"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[23]="DEVICE_URI=socket://zxy.ddns.net:9100"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[24]="PRINTER_INFO=POS-80-Series"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[25]="PRINTER_LOCATION="
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[26]="PRINTER=POS-80-Series"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[27]="PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[28]="CUPS_FILETYPE=document"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[29]="FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-raster"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[30]="AUTH_I****"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/texttopdf (PID 9475)
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf (PID 9476)
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster (PID 9477)
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Started filter /usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertopos (PID 9478)
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Started backend /usr/lib/cups/backend/socket (PID 9479)
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] PID 9478 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertopos) stopped with status 102 (No such file or directory)
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] OUTFORMAT=\"(null)\", so output format will be CUPS/PWG Raster
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Page = 227x595; 11,0 to 215,595
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] pdftopdf: Last filter determined by the PPD: rastertopos; FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE: application/vnd.cups-raster => pdftopdf will not log pages in page_log.
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] execv failed: No such file or directory
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] STATE: +connecting-to-device
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Looking up \"zxy.ddns.net\"...
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] STATE: -connecting-to-device
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] blabla.ddns.net=45.150.247.146
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] PID 9475 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/texttopdf) exited with no errors.
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] PID 9476 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/pdftopdf) exited with no errors.
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Color Manager: Calibration Mode/Off
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Calling FindDeviceById(cups-POS-80-Series)
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Found device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_POS_80_Series
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Calling org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Device.Get(ProfilingInhibitors)
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Calling FindDeviceById(cups-POS-80-Series)
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Found device /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/devices/cups_POS_80_Series
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Calling GetProfileForQualifiers(Gray.....)
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Found profile /org/freedesktop/ColorManager/profiles/POS_80_Series_Gray__
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Calling org.freedesktop.ColorManager.Profile.Get(Filename)
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Use profile filename: \'\'
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Color Manager: ICC Profile: 
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Ghostscript using Any-Part-of-Pixel method to fill paths.
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Ghostscript command line: gs -dQUIET -dPARANOIDSAFER -dNOPAUSE -dBATCH -dNOINTERPOLATE -dNOMEDIAATTRS -dShowAcroForm -sstdout=%stderr -sOutputFile=%stdout -sDEVICE=cups -r203x203 -dDEVICEWIDTHPOINTS=227 -dDEVICEHEIGHTPOINTS=595 -dcupsBitsPerColor=1 -dcupsColorOrder=0 -dcupsColorSpace=3 -scupsPageSizeName=X80mmY210mm -I/usr/share/cups/fonts -c \'<</.HWMargins[11.000000 0.000000 12.000000 0.000000] /Margins[0 0]>>setpagedevice\' -f -_
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[0]=\"CUPS_CACHEDIR=/var/cache/cups\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[1]=\"CUPS_DATADIR=/usr/share/cups\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[2]=\"CUPS_DOCROOT=/usr/share/cups/doc-root\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[3]=\"CUPS_FONTPATH=/usr/share/cups/fonts\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[4]=\"CUPS_REQUESTROOT=/var/spool/cups\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[5]=\"CUPS_SERVERBIN=/usr/lib/cups\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[6]=\"CUPS_SERVERROOT=/etc/cups\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[7]=\"CUPS_STATEDIR=/run/cups\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[8]=\"HOME=/var/spool/cups/tmp\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[9]=\"PATH=/usr/lib/cups/filter:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/usr/bin\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[10]=\"SERVER_ADMIN=root@pizzalinkess\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[11]=\"SOFTWARE=CUPS/2.2.8\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[12]=\"USER=root\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[13]=\"CUPS_MAX_MESSAGE=2047\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[14]=\"CUPS_SERVER=/run/cups/cups.sock\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[15]=\"CUPS_ENCRYPTION=IfRequested\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[16]=\"IPP_PORT=631\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[17]=\"CHARSET=utf-8\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[18]=\"LANG=en.UTF-8\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[19]=\"PPD=/etc/cups/ppd/POS-80-Series.ppd\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[20]=\"RIP_MAX_CACHE=128m\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[21]=\"CONTENT_TYPE=text/plain\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[22]=\"DEVICE_URI=socket://zxy.ddns.net:9100\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[23]=\"PRINTER_INFO=POS-80-Series\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[24]=\"PRINTER_LOCATION=\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[25]=\"PRINTER=POS-80-Series\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[26]=\"PRINTER_STATE_REASONS=none\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[27]=\"CUPS_FILETYPE=document\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[28]=\"FINAL_CONTENT_TYPE=application/vnd.cups-raster\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] envp[29]=\"AUTH_INFO_REQUIRED=none\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Start rendering...
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Processing page 1...
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Error: /ioerror in --showpage--
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Operand stack:
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] true   (/tmp/gs_oJ2BOA)   --nostringval--   1   true
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Execution stack:
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   showpage   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   showpage   showpage   false   1   %stopped_push   2045   2   3   %oparray_pop   2044   2   3   %oparray_pop   2025   2   3   %oparray_pop   showpage   2026   4   3   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage   2   1   1   showpage   %for_pos_int_continue   2029   4   7   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage   1890   3   9   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Dictionary stack:
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] --dict:969/1684(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:83/200(L)--   --dict:83/200(L)--   --dict:133/256(ro)(G)--   --dict:310/450(ro)(G)--   --dict:32/32(L)--   --dict:6/9(L)--   --dict:6/20(L)--
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Current allocation mode is local
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Last OS error: Broken pipe
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] GPL Ghostscript 9.26: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Rendering completed
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] PID 9477 (/usr/lib/cups/filter/gstoraster) stopped with status 1.
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] Hint: Try setting the LogLevel to "debug" to find out more.
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] hrDeviceDesc=\"Unknown\"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] prtGeneralCurrentLocalization type is 0, expected 2!
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] backendWaitLoop(snmp_fd=5, addr=0x5573538f0e48, side_cb=0x557352cab1d0)
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] PID 9479 (/usr/lib/cups/backend/socket) exited with no errors.
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] End of messages
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] printer-state=3(idle)
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] printer-state-message="Rendering completed"
D [04/Jan/2019:19:50:44 +0000] [Job 13] printer-state-reasons=none
```

Answer (score 2):

Wanted to add this for posterity in case someone gets a similar error in the future.

I am running a Raspberry Pi and Debian/Raspbian Bullseye and trying to make a Rollo thermal label printer work with CUPS.

As of this writing, Debian is tracking Ghostscript 9.53. CUPS is calling the gstoraster filter, which in turn calls ghostscript, which crashes with an error message similar to this:

```
E [14/Dec/2021:19:47:45 +0000] [Job 5] Unable to open raster stream - : Broken pipe
D [14/Dec/2021:19:47:45 +0000] [Job 5] Error: /ioerror in --showpage--
D [14/Dec/2021:19:47:45 +0000] [Job 5] Operand stack:
D [14/Dec/2021:19:47:45 +0000] [Job 5] true   (/var/spool/cups/tmp/gs_tmfIcM)   --nostringval--   1   true
D [14/Dec/2021:19:47:45 +0000] [Job 5] Execution stack:
D [14/Dec/2021:19:47:45 +0000] [Job 5] %interp_exit   .runexec2   --nostringval--   showpage   --nostringval--   2   %stopped_push   --nostringval--   showpage   showpage   false   1   %stopped_push   1990   2   3   %oparray_pop   1989   2   3   %oparray_pop   1977   2   3   %oparray_pop   showpage   1978   4   3   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage   2   1   1   showpage   %for_pos_int_continue   1981   4   7   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage   1840   3   9   %oparray_pop   showpage   showpage
D [14/Dec/2021:19:47:45 +0000] [Job 5] Dictionary stack:
D [14/Dec/2021:19:47:45 +0000] [Job 5] --dict:741/1123(ro)(G)--   --dict:1/20(G)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:80/200(L)--   --dict:133/256(ro)(G)--   --dict:320/325(ro)(G)--   --dict:33/64(L)--   --dict:6/9(L)--   --dict:7/20(L)--
D [14/Dec/2021:19:47:45 +0000] [Job 5] Current allocation mode is local
D [14/Dec/2021:19:47:45 +0000] [Job 5] Last OS error: Broken pipe
D [14/Dec/2021:19:47:45 +0000] [Job 5] GPL Ghostscript 9.53.3: Unrecoverable error, exit code 1
```

Exactly what I did to fix:

Add the following line to `/etc/apt/sources.list`: `deb http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian/ oldstable main contrib non-free rpi`

`sudo apt update`

Check the output of `apt-cache policy ghostscript`

```
ghostscript:
  Installed: 9.53.3~dfsg-7+deb11u1
  Candidate: 9.53.3~dfsg-7+deb11u1
  Version table:
 *** 9.53.3~dfsg-7+deb11u1 500
        500 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian bullseye/main armhf Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u4 500
        500 http://raspbian.raspberrypi.org/raspbian oldstable/main armhf Packages
```

Then you need to install the downgraded version of ghostscript with its dependencies. I did that with the following command:

```
sudo apt install ghostscript=9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u4 libgs9=9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u4 libgs9-common=9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u4
```

Then it worked!!

Comment: This appears to be the same answer as at least one of the others, but better formatted?

Comment: I believe that my answer was more comprehensive in exactly what to do, as I still had to connect some dots when following the answer that was already here.

Answer (score 1):

I just solved a problem very similar to this. To solve it, I added "oldstable" to my Debian sources.list and then I was able to downgrade several packages. I downgraded:

- printer-driver-hpcups to 3.16.11+repack0-3
- ghostscript, ghostsctipt-x, libgs9, libgs9-common to 9.26a~dfsg-0+deb9u2

Comment: This appears to be substantively the same answer as the existing one.

Comment: My answer names all the packages that need a downgrade, what version to put each to, and how to adjust the sources.list to allow this to happen. I would have made a comment on the existing answer, but I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: Unfortunately these packages don't exist anymore.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem today; a previously working printer refused to print, status "Filter failed".

Got it working again by downgrading Ghostscript to the version before:

```
$ apt-cache policy ghostscript
ghostscript:
  Installed: 9.26a~dfsg-0+deb9u1
  Candidate: 9.27~dfsg-1
  Version table:
     9.27~dfsg-1 500
        500 http://ftp.debian.org/debian testing/main amd64 Packages
 *** 9.26a~dfsg-0+deb9u1 500
        500 http://ftp.de.debian.org/debian stable/main amd64 Packages
```

Now I'm holding that version and watch for their next changelog.

Answer (score 0):

Followed the instructions, including the alow-downgrade-insecure=yes option added to the specific repository.

Following error still remains:

root@raspberrypi:/home/pi# apt-get install ghostscript=9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u4 libgs                                                                             9=9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u4 libgs9-common=9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u4
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Version '9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u4' for 'ghostscript' was not found
E: Version '9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u4' for 'libgs9' was not found
E: Version '9.27~dfsg-2+deb10u4' for 'libgs9-common' was not found

Any advise?

Comment: This does not really answer the question. If you have a different question, you can ask it by clicking [Ask Question](https://serverfault.com/questions/ask). To get notified when this question gets new answers, you can [follow this question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/345661). Once you have enough [reputation](https://serverfault.com/help/whats-reputation), you can also [add a bounty](https://serverfault.com/help/privileges/set-bounties) to draw more attention to this question. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/539661)